# Is there any way I can access an access database I set to read only from other computers on another computer?

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

Basically I secured the database to only open fully on one system but now I need to change it from another system. Is there anyway I can do this?
Thanks

Edit: The database is a .accdb
I changed the file privileges by right clicking the file

Comment: If you set it based on users, then try shift+right clicking and run as a different user?  This will most likely only work with network/AD computers though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem is is that I did the work in their company and now I need to fix it from my computer in a different building. I have it on a usb. I suppose I am going to have to travel to the company and edit the security there and bring it back here?   Thanks, Kieran

Comment: What if you were to open the file, do a Save as as a different copy, and then just replace the old one with the new modified one at lunch time when everyone logs off.